# What's the best way to add a new property source in Spring?

Tags: spring, configuration

I'd like to add a new property source that could be used to read property values in an application. I'd like to do this using Spring. I have a piece of code like this in a @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {        
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    MutablePropertySources sources = new MutablePropertySources();
    MyCustomPropertySource propertySource = new MyCustomPropertySource("my custom property source");
    sources.addFirst(propertySource);
    properties.setPropertySources(sources);
    return properties;
}
```

This seems to work pretty well. However, what it is also doing is overriding other property values (e.g. server.port property in application.properties file used by spring boot) which I don't want to overwrite. So the basic question is what's the best way to add this propertysource but not have it override other properties. Any way to grab the existing propertysources and simply add on to it?

Answer (score 8):

I got this working by adding a custom initiailizer to my spring boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class)
            .initializers(new MyContextInitializer())  // <---- here
            .run(args);
    }

}
```

Where `MyContextInitializer` contains: -

```
public class MyContextInitializer implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment();

        // Create map for properites and add first (important)
        Map<String, Object> myProperties = new HashMap<>();
        myProperties.put("some-prop", "custom-value");
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
            new MapPropertySource("my-props", myProperties));
    }

}
```

Note, if your `application.yaml` contains: -

```
some-prop: some-value
another-prop: this is ${some-prop} property
```

Then the `initialize` method will update the `some-prop` to `custom-value` and when the app loads it will have the following values at run-time:

```
some-prop: custom-value
another-prop: this is custom-value property
```

Note, if the `initialize` method did a simple `System.setProperty` call i.e.

```
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment();
        System.setProperty("some-prop", "custom-value");
    }
```

... then the `another-prop` would be equal to `this is some-value property` which is not what we generally want (and we lose the power of Spring config property resolution).

Comment: It's better to use `OriginTrackedMapPropertySource` than `HashMap` for new property sources

Comment: Can you explain why please?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting IgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to TRUE. I had a similar problem which I was able to resolve in this way. In my case, I had another placeholderconfigurer, which was working - but properties in the second one were not being resolved unless I set this property to TRUE.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {        
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(Boolean.TRUE);
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Comment: This one is not a solution, but helped me identify the key I need to use when I inject `PropertyResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility (after lots of experimentation, it's what worked for me) would be to declare your `PropertySource` inside a `ApplicationContextInitializer` and then inject that one in your `SpringBootServletInitializer`:

```
public class MyPropertyInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationPropertyInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MyPropertySource ps = new MyPropertySource();
        applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
    }

}
```

```
public class MyInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return super.configure(builder.initializers(new MyPropertyInitializer()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps add your propertySource straight into environment once it is initialized.

**EDIT:** As this is done AFTER the class is processed, you cannot expect the `@Value` annotations to pick up anything from this particular PropertySource in the same `@Configuration` class - or any other that is loaded before.

```
@Configuration
public class YourPropertyConfigClass{

    @Value("${fromCustomSource}")
    String prop; // failing - property source not yet existing

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        env.getPropertySources().addFirst(
             new MyCustomPropertySource("my custom property source"));
    }
}

@Configuration
@DependsOn("YourPropertyConfigClass")
public class PropertyUser {

    @Value("${fromCustomSource}")
    String prop; // not failing
}
```

You could move the `@PostConstruct` to a separate `@Configuration` class and mark other classes using those properties `@DependOn("YourPropertyConfigClass")` (this works - but perhaps there is a better way to force configuration order?).

Anyway - it is only worth it, if `MyCustomPropertySource` cannot be simply added using `@PropertySource("file.properties")` annotation - which would solve the problem for simple property files.

Comment: I gave this a shot but it didn't seem to work. I just replaced my method with this one but then all of my @value annotation resolving started to fail. I think it's the right track though.

Comment: Are you resolving .@Value annotation during configuration (in @Configuration classes) - or is it done later?

Comment: It's in the configuration class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit. I'll give it a shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement PropertySourceFactory as such:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

public class CustomPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use the following property source:

```
@PropertySource(name="custom-prop-source", value="", factory=CustomPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

Kind of hack-ish, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `EnvironmentPostProcessor`

You can for example read out database properties with it and make them available on the spring environment:

```
@Order
public class CustomPropertiesProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    
    ...

    
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(100);

    // Environment
    environment
      .getPropertySources()
      .addFirst(new MapPropertySource("yourPrefix", properties));
}
```

Do not forget to have it registered in `/META-INF/spring.factories` (should be in the resources folder in case of a maven project):

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
com.your.package.CustomPropertiesProcessor
```

You can inject `PropertyResolver` to check how to access the properties (because you do not need to put the prefix on the key).