How to add computed properties in a spring environment so as to use as placeholders in properties file?
I have a Spring Boot application configured in the standard way: when it loads it takes properties from an application.yaml file, and injects them in several configuration beans, annotated with @Component and @ConfigurationProperties.
I need some of the properties to be custom computed. Those properties are about network configuration: subnet mask and address, broadcast IP, etc. There are quite a lot of them, they vary server to server, and we have a lots of servers. I would rather not multiply the number of property files only for that reason.
I have a LocalNetwork bean that exposes the network properties, and a service that builds it. Now I would like the properties to be usable as placeholders in other properties defined in application.yaml:
hosts:
   my-first-host: ${local-network.local.ip}
   my-second-host: ${local-network.default-loopback.ip}
   my-third-host: ${local-network.local.broacast-ip}
somewhere:
   else:
      broadcast-to: ${hosts.my-third-host} 
      # I could do without this double indirection, 
      # but it would be so nice to have it.

I could use the LocalNetwork bean as dependency injected to other beans, but it would make this part of configuration rather obscure. I prefer application.yaml to explicitly pass some readable ${local-network.local.ip} variable as value for other configuration properties.
I've come up with a way of making it work partially:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ServicesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalNetwork networkInterface() {
        return LocalNetworkBuilder.build();
    }

    // ...
    // Lots of other things here
    // ...
        
    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(LocalNetwork localNetwork) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putIfAbsent("local-network.default-loopback.ip", 
                localNetwork.getLoopbackDefault().ip(0).getHostAddress());
        properties.putIfAbsent("local-network.local.ip", 
                localNetwork.getNetwork().ip(0).getHostAddress());
        properties.putIfAbsent("local-network.local.broadcast-ip", 
                localNetwork.getNetwork().broadcastIp().getHostAddress());

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        p.setProperties(properties);

        return p;
    }
}

But I don't like it because of two reasons:

It is hidden in a configuration bean that is not explicitly doing this task.
broadcast-to: ${my-third-host} does not resolve, with error Could not resolve placeholder 'my-third-host' in value '${my-third-host}'. It does resolve my-third-host: ${local-network.local.broacast-ip}, though.

What would be the orthodox way to implement this place-holder mechanism?
N.B. This is not for a server application. It's a testing application, and it will be installed by operators on servers. The operators will probably edit an external application.yaml to their own needs. This is why keeping the properties file readable is very important.
N.B.2 The reason why I prefer not directly using ${local-network.local.broacast-ip}, but instead use it to initialize my-third-host, and then use ${my-third-host} in the rest of the applications file is about readability: all operators are familiar with the names of the hosts used across the company, so they will have an easier time understanding the set up in this way.

Maybe something like Spring Cloud Config would help you? I never used it myself so I cannot come up with an example, but somehow it sounds as you could use "externalized configuration in a distributed system".

Thanks for the suggestions, @cyberbrain, but this application is not going on cloud, and it is not a server application. It's a testing application, and will be installed on lots of different equipment. Some have two network cards, some have a loopback adapter, etc.

regarding the 2 reasons: for reason #1 - I don't think you can do anything about that, since for your use case you require a programmatic resolving of a property, and custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is the correct approach. Regarding #2, that should actually work, so key question is where exactly is this somewhere.else.broadcast-to located? Also is there any reason you are not using ${hosts.my-third-host} in that place directly?

@asgarov1: The reason why I prefer not directly using ${local-network.local.broacast-ip}, but instead use it to initialize my-third-host, and then use ${my-third-host} in the rest of the applications file is about readability: all operators are familiar with the names of the hosts used across the company, so they will have an easier time understanding the set up in this way. Currently, all properties (except the computed ones) are defined in only one application.yaml which is a resource of the application.

I believe my problem is linked to this question, and the first answer would do it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714491/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-new-property-source-in-spring

It turns out that adding properties directly into the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer by way of replacing the default constructor with a @Bean works in somehow, but not fully:

The added properties are made available to the application.yaml, and it's possible to refer to them with a ${...}
BUT they're not fully integrated in the property resolution process

For example, consider the following configuration:
hosts:
   my-first-host: ${local-network.local.ip}
   ...
somewhere:
   else:
      broadcast-to: ${hosts.my-third-host}

If local-network.local.ip = 167.1.1.1, then hosts.my-first-host is correctly set to 167.1.1.1 but broadcast-to is set to local-network.local-ip, without further resolution.
A way that works is adding a ApplicationContextInitializer that adds the properties as a PropertySource:
public class NetworkPropertiesContextInitializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    private final LocalNetwork localNetwork;

    public NetworkPropertiesContextInitializer() {
        this.localNetwork = LocalNetworkBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment();

        // Create map for properties and add first (important)
        Map<String, Object> networkProperties = new HashMap<>();
        networkProperties.put("local-network.default-loopback.ip", 
                localNetwork.getLoopbackDefault().ip(0).getHostAddress());
        networkProperties.put("local-network.local.ip", 
                localNetwork.getNetwork().ip(0).getHostAddress());
        networkProperties.put("local-network.local.broadcast-ip", 
                localNetwork.getNetwork().broadcastIp().getHostAddress());

        // Add properties as a new property source:
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(
                new MapPropertySource("networkProperties",
                    networkProperties));

    }
}

Then you need to refer to the context initializer from the application's entry points.
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {ServicesConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .initializers(new NetworkPropertiesContextInitializer())
                .run(args);
    }
}

And from test spring configuration it would be something like:
@SpringBootTest(classes = ServicesConfiguration.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = NetworkPropertiesContextInitializer.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringIntegrationConfig {

}

References:

I've got the solution from this question and its first answer: What's the best way to add a new property source in Spring?
How to link a @SpringBootTest to a context initialiser: Spring boot test: context loaded for every test?

